# OpenCV Hu Moments Android

Tags: java, android, image, opencv, android-studio

I'm developing an application that takes the HU moments of an image that was taken with the device camera. The image before reaching the calculation of HU moments was: grayscale, gausseanBlurr, binarization, canny algorithm, applied method findcontour () and finally calculate the HU moments. All this has been done with OpenCV on Android Studio.

```
public void Hu()
{

    Mat imagenOriginal;
    imagenOriginal = new Mat();
    Mat binario;
    binario = new Mat();
    Mat Canny;
    Canny = new Mat();

    Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, imagenOriginal);
    Mat gris= new Mat(imagenOriginal.width() ,imagenOriginal.height(),imagenOriginal.type());
    Imgproc.cvtColor(imagenOriginal, gris, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
    org.opencv.core.Size s = new Size(3,3);
    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(gris, gris, s, 2);

    Imgproc.threshold(gris, binario, 100, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);
    Imgproc.Canny(gris, Canny, 50, 50 * 3);

    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();

    Mat hierarcy = new Mat();

    Imgproc.findContours(Canny, contours, hierarcy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    Imgproc.drawContours(Canny, contours, -1, new Scalar(Math.random() * 255, Math.random() * 255, Math.random() * 255));

    Moments momento = new Moments();
    Mat hu= new Mat();

    momento = Imgproc.moments(contours.get(0), false); // ERROR LINE

    Imgproc.HuMoments(momento, hu);

}
```

When I perform the calculation Hu moments is when I have the error because I made a test each time q some algorithm was applied to the image.
The code of how to get the HU moments was taken from here:

[Android: using hu moments opencv function to get the feature value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20783022/android-using-hu-moments-opencv-function-to-get-the-feature-value)

I have also understood that the HU moments are saved in the Hu variable, but I see no way to print all values.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Brother: Yes I have the same problem and I looked for al the WEB with no results :( , but then after think a while I get a moment of clarity: If I have all moments (center, normalized,raw,etc) in Moments function why I can't use directly the formula in order to get the Hu moments, so I did that and it works!!, please check below if this help you too...

```
 Moments p = new Moments();

        List<Moments> nu = new ArrayList<Moments>(contours.size());

        for(int i=0; i<contours.size(); i++)
        {
            nu.add(i, Imgproc.moments(contours.get(i),false));
             p=nu.get(i);

        }
```

//finish now calculate manually the HU Moments
            double[] moments = new double[8];

```
        double
                n20 = p.get_nu20(),
                n02 = p.get_nu02(),
                n30 = p.get_nu30(),
                n12 = p.get_nu12(),
                n21 = p.get_nu21(),
                n03 = p.get_nu03(),
                n11 = p.get_nu11();

        //First moment
        moments[0] = n20 + n02;

        //Second moment
        moments[1] = Math.pow((n20 - 02), 2) + Math.pow(2 * n11, 2);

        //Third moment
        moments[2] = Math.pow(n30 - (3 * (n12)), 2)
                + Math.pow((3 * n21 - n03), 2);

        //Fourth moment
        moments[3] = Math.pow((n30 + n12), 2) + Math.pow((n12 + n03), 2);

        //Fifth moment
        moments[4] = (n30 - 3 * n12) * (n30 + n12)
                * (Math.pow((n30 + n12), 2) - 3 * Math.pow((n21 + n03), 2))
                + (3 * n21 - n03) * (n21 + n03)
                * (3 * Math.pow((n30 + n12), 2) - Math.pow((n21 + n03), 2));

        //Sixth moment
        moments[5] = (n20 - n02)
                * (Math.pow((n30 + n12), 2) - Math.pow((n21 + n03), 2))
                + 4 * n11 * (n30 + n12) * (n21 + n03);

        //Seventh moment
        moments[6] = (3 * n21 - n03) * (n30 + n12)
                * (Math.pow((n30 + n12), 2) - 3 * Math.pow((n21 + n03), 2))
                + (n30 - 3 * n12) * (n21 + n03)
                * (3 * Math.pow((n30 + n12), 2) - Math.pow((n21 + n03), 2));

        //Eighth moment
        moments[7] = n11 * (Math.pow((n30 + n12), 2) - Math.pow((n03 + n21), 2))
                - (n20 - n02) * (n30 + n12) * (n03 + n21);

        return moments;
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much to you and your moment of clarity. But I have a doubt in your code.


  The manual calculation of Hu moments you do inside the FOR loop or out of it?

  If you do it outside, what is the value of "p" ? "P = nu.get (i)" would use the last value of "i"?


if it does inside, we would have eight moments for each "i" moments of "nu" list, finally how many huMoments we have for each image? I need to have 8 huMoments for each image, not for each contour , no?

Comment: and now I have an error on the line in the cycle FOR "Improc.moments (contour.get (i), false)". it say "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.moments_0: (JZ) [D". You know how to fix it? I get nothing on the internet. thx! @Luis

Comment: I think you better have to use the max contour, then obtain the Hu moments